# How to display text at runtime throught LightBox

Tags: jquery

how to show few text in light box instead of image. i found that most of the time light box is used to show images but i want to show text or suppose a asp.net gridview inside a light box. i found jquery light box plugin available the url is http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/. from here sample i did not find any way to show text in light box instead of image . So please tell me how to show text in light box instead of image and the text i will pass at run time.

thanks.

Comment: it seems that what you need is a [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), right?

Comment: @ifaour, You should post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

it seems that what you need is a [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), right?

EDIT: okay, what about [Facebox](http://chriswanstrath.com/facebox/)? it supports DIVs

Comment: sorry i want to use lightbox not jquery dialog. i hard that we can show div adorn with custom text through lightbox.show me the way if u know any solution. thanks